# Why does nesting "yield from" statements (generator delegation) produce terminating `None` value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator, yield, yield-from

Is it possible to nest `yield from` statements?

The simple form is obvious:

```
def try_yield1():
    x = range(3)
    yield from x
```

Which produces:

```
0
1
2
```

But what if I have nested generators?

```
def try_yield_nested():
   x = [range(3) for _ in range(4)]
    yield from ((yield from y) for y in x)
```

This produces:

```
0
1
2
None # why?
0
1
2
None # ...
0
1
2
None # ...
```

Why does it produce `None` if I used `yield from` (even though it is nested)?

I know I can do something like:

```
from itertools import chain

def try_yield_nested_alternative():
    x = [range(3) for _ in range(4)]
    yield from chain.from_iterable(x)
```

Which produces the same output leaving out the `None` (which is what I expect). I can also write a simple loop:

```
for x in [range(3) for _ in range(3)]:
    yield from x
```

But, I thought it would be more pythonic to use nested delegation (preferably even `yield from x from y` or `yield from x for x in y`, but that is not proper syntax). Why is it not working as I expect?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`yield` is an expression, it'll evaluate whatever you `send(value)` it. Simply put, if you send it nothing, you'll get a `None` output because the value of `yield` would be `None`.

`yield from` itself is equal to `None`, and you're using two of them. At the second `yield from` you're iterating a list, which inputs the generator with the items of that list, but you're also using `yield from` to return that generator expression, which returns the list and also itself which is equivalent to `None` at each iteration, thus why after each item iteration of range you get a `None`.

Essentially this is what is happening:

1. `(yield from y) for y in x` yields the values, [0, 1, 2]
2. `yield from` yields the values from the previous, and also `yield from` from previous which is `None`.
3. Evaluating to [0, 1, 2] and then adding a `None` due to `yield from` in `(yield from y) for y in x`.

Unfortunately, there is no way to get rid of the `None` output, due to the nature of the expression. You're better off using `from_iterable`.

Source explaining yield expression;
https://docs.python.org/2.5/ref/yieldexpr.html